# Window Sum with Condition in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, cumulative-sum

Using Tableau 10.5 I'm trying to create table/chart that shows the total of new ("Standing Start") Sales over a rolling 52-week window.  The chart image below shows the sum of sales by week from new (standing start) customers within the 52-week window spanning from ISO week 201733 to 201832; the line shows the running total of the sales.

[image: Running Total of New Sales]

The following image shows the last few weeks of data for the chart.

[image: Underlying chart data]

"New Sales" are defined as customers with a start week within 52 weeks of the reporting/ISO week (in the example where 201832 is the report week, customers with a start week between 201733 and 201832 are included).  The running total of Sales between those same weeks is taken, with the value of interest being the running total value in the final week (5,046,546 in the example).

What I need is to display the corresponding 52-week total for each reporting week (so the values would be circa 5 million each week) and the bars would be relatively flat (allowing for sales growth, etc). My specific issue is that I can't figure out how to define the window (i.e. New accounts only) when doing the window/moving calculation.

I hope my description is clear enough to illustrate what my objective is.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT/UPDATE (to further clarify the question):

The following example table shows Sales made between 201824 and 201827 from accounts opened in the same period.  In week 201824, only accounts opened in 201824 have any sales (value of 1).  In week 201825, there are now 2 weeks' of accounts: those opened in week 201824 and those opened in week 201825, making sales of 2 and 1 respectively.  Each subsequent week has an extra week's worth of accounts contributing to the sales total of 20.

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 201824 | 201825 | 201826 | 201827 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |      1 |
|        |        |      1 |      2 |
|        |      1 |      2 |      3 |
|      1 |      2 |      3 |      4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

To continue with the example, the next table shows similar data but with the time period moved by 1 week:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 201825 | 201826 | 201827 | 201828 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |      2 |
|        |        |      2 |      3 |
|        |      2 |      3 |      4 |
|      2 |      3 |      4 |      5 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The sum of sales in this table is 30: accounts opened in week 201825 contribute 14 (2 + 3 + 4 + 5), those opened in the second week contributed 9 (2 + 3 + 4), and so on.

These two tables describe the methodology I'm looking for, and the results I'm looking for will be something like the following:

```
+--------+--------+
| 201827 | 201828 |
+--------+--------+
|     20 |     30 |
+--------+--------+
```

If I were doing something similar in SQL, the following gives me the result I need:

```
;with d AS 
(
    select s.ISOWk, a.OSW as StartWeek, sum(s.Sales) as Sales
    from accs a
    join sales s
        on a.ID = s.ID
    where s.ISOWk >= 201701
        and a.OSW >= 201701
    group by s.ISOWk, a.OSW
)
select c.ISOWk, sum(case when d.ISOWk between FYS and c.ISOWk and StartWeek between FYS and c.ISOWk then Vol else 0 end) as Rolling_ss_vol
from d
cross join (select distinct ISOWk, FYS from tblCalendar c where ISOWk between 201801 and 201835) c
group by c.ISOWk
order by ISOWk
```

Where FYS (front year start) is linked to the ISO week and indicates when the current sales period began (ie. 52 weeks prior).

Answer (score 1):

I converted the iso dates to regular dates on your sample file. This made it easier to do DATEDIFF calculation. I found this formula on Tableau's forum for this conversion.

```
DATEADD('week',INT(MID(STR([Start Week]), 5,2))-1,DATE("01/01/"+(MID(STR([Start Week]), 1,4))))
```

I repeated the same for customer iso week.

Then made a [cust start] LOD to make sure I compute the datediff correctly.

```
{fixed [Cust No] : min([start_week_date])}
```

Then made a [Sales within 52] calc field

```
if datediff('week',[cust start], [iso_week_date])<52 then [Sales] end
```

Finally, the [window_sum_sales] uses [Sales within 52] inside it.

```
window_sum(sum([Sales within 52]),-51,0)
```

Hopefully, this is what you're looking for.

workbook link https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxw5e2783la4fl4/20180906_stackoverflow_question.twbx?dl=0

Comment: Not quite.  For example: The value in week 62 should be the sum of sales between weeks 11 and 62 for accounts opened between weeks 11 and 62 only.  I think your calculation is including sales for accounts opened in week 10 when calculating sales in week 15 because they are less than 52 weeks old at that point.  This isn't quite what I'm after.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Sure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3x6yjw44qf7oinl/Sample%20Data%20for%20Rolling%20Standing%20Start%20Analysis.xlsx?dl=0 this file contains some sample/dummy data

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Your answer still isn't quite right: the total for week 201832 should be 5,046,546.  I've edited my question in the hope I can provide a better description of what I need.